# JavaScript Variable in Modal Window with Post or something else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need a little help. i have a javascript with the variable row_id. i need the variable in my bootstrap modal window. can anybody help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $("#myModal").modal();
 $("tr button").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var row_id = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-row-id");

    alert(row_id);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: access directly row_id in bootstrap js

Comment: do you have a snippet for this? i am not very fit in jquery

Comment: please show where is your variable defined is it in global scope ? or inside a function context ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append your variable on your modal body or title.

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="mtitle">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="mbody">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Note the id mbody and mtitle.
Here's how to append your variable

```
$('#mbody').html(yourvariable);
```

or

```
 $('#mtitle').html(yourvariable)
```

Comment: okay. this works fine. and how would it now work if i want to put there a form with a submit button for a database update. the form is no problem but i have to catch the data selct * from blabla where id =   . and here i need to know how write it.

Comment: mark my answer as correct if its solve the problem. you can atleast try to search on how to do it. then if you have a problem with your codes. show your codes and your problem on different thread.

Answer (score 0):

here you see data-row-id.

```
while($erg_motor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_erg_motor))

                                {

                                    $body.='
                                    <tr data-row-id='.$erg_motor['id'].'>
                                        <td>'.$erg_motor['id'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$erg_motor['motor_name'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$erg_motor['motor_mail'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$erg_motor['motor_fabrikat'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$erg_motor['motor_modell'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$erg_motor['motor_ez'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$erg_motor['motor_km'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$erg_motor['motor_kraftstoff'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$erg_motor['motor_standort'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$erg_motor['motor_mailsperre'].'</td>
                                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button></td>
                                    </tr>';
                                }
```